# Multi View Controller Navigation in Swift

Tags: swift, animation, menu, navigation, segue

## Side Menu Navigation in Swift

### Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.0

My ultimate goal is to be able to easily (normally) transverse/navigate through my view controllers like as shown below.

[image: Navigation]

I want to be able to navigate from view controller to view controller with a common side menu. To this point, I have come up with an incredibly *hacky* way to accomplish this wherein when I select a view controller in the side menu, it goes dismisses the side menu, then it precedes to present the next view controller from that one, and assuming that is not the target view controller, a window temporarily covers its contents while I segue from that view controller to the target view controller.

[image: Path through storyboard]

#### Unique paths of view controllers to display from side menu.

[image: Animation Paths]
**Note:** *each colour in the above image is another path the app can take after something have being tapped in the side menu.*

There are so many things wrong with this implementation I don't even know where to start. On rare occasions, you can see the contents of the intermediary view controller in between segues. Also the animation can be a bit choppy and distorted due to the amount of segues requires to actually get to the target view in some cases. Not to mention the immense difficulty and complexity now required to add another row to my side menu. And I know full well this is atrocious and am desperately trying to find a solution not my complex navigational problem. Of recent I have experimented with using container views and putting my side menu at the bottom of my stack rather than at the top as is right now, but it hasn't amounted to anything.

---

The past few weeks I have been driving myself insane trying to find out how to do this. I have found countless implementations of side menus, but all that I have found to this date will only show the side menu on only one view controller instead of showing up on all of the side menu's target and treating them if they are all *on the same level* so to say. In essence, the side menu needs to be able to come up on all of the 3 view controllers and take away the need to *hackily* segue over a view controller. As well, it would be quite ideal if this side menu is easily scalable so I can add multiple sections to the side menu with ease.

---

Comment: I believe this( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kwCfFG5fDA ) will help you. The best part of it is you can invoke it from any screen, position on navigation stack dont matter.

Comment: @Noah any feedback on my answer

Comment: Have you tried this using an invisible tab bar instead? instead of presenting and dismissing view controllers you could set the selected index to show the view controller you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I've created a sample project for this question. You can see the output in the above image. basically what I did is created a wrapper class around the Sidebar and then I used it whenever I want :)

Sidebar

```
import UIKit
protocol SidebarDelegate {
    func sidbarDidOpen()
    func sidebarDidClose(with item: Int?)
}
class SidebarLauncher: NSObject{

    var view: UIView?
    var delegate: SidebarDelegate?
    var vc: NavigationViewController?
    init(delegate: SidebarDelegate) {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func show(){
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -bounds.width, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height))
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! NavigationViewController
        v.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor),
            vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor),
            vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor),
            vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -60)
            ])
        vc.delegate = self
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        v.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:))))
        self.view = v
        self.vc = vc
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(v)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.view?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view!.frame.width, height: self.view!.frame.height)
            self.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        }, completion: {completed in
            self.delegate?.sidbarDidOpen()
        })

    }

    @objc func handleTapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        closeSidebar(option: nil)
    }
    func closeSidebar(option: Int?){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            if let view = self.view{
                view.frame = CGRect(x: -view.frame.width, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
                self.view?.backgroundColor = .clear

            }
        }, completion: {completed in
            self.view?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.view = nil
            self.vc = nil
            self.delegate?.sidebarDidClose(with: option)
        })
    }

}
extension SidebarLauncher: NavigationDelegate{
    func navigation(didSelect: Int?) {
        closeSidebar(option: didSelect)
    }
}
```

NavigationController

```
import UIKit
protocol NavigationDelegate{
    func navigation(didSelect: Int?)
}

class NavigationViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLaunchVC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonSecondViewController: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonThirdViewController: UIButton!


    var delegate: NavigationDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [buttonLaunchVC,buttonSecondViewController,buttonThirdViewController].forEach({
            $0?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        })
    }

    @objc func didSelect(_ sender: UIButton){
        switch sender {
        case buttonLaunchVC:
            delegate?.navigation(didSelect: 0)
        case buttonSecondViewController:
            delegate?.navigation(didSelect: 1)
        case buttonThirdViewController:
            delegate?.navigation(didSelect: 2)
        default:
            break
        }
    }


    @IBAction func CloseMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.navigation(didSelect: nil)
    }


}
```

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func OpenMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        SidebarLauncher(delegate: self ).show()
    }

}
extension ViewController: SidebarDelegate{
    func sidbarDidOpen() {
        print("Sidebar opened")
    }

    func sidebarDidClose(with item: Int?) {
        guard let item = item else {return}
        print("Did select \(item)")
        switch item {
        case 0:
           break
        case 1:
            let v = UIStoryboard.main.SecondVC()
            present(v!, animated: true)
        case 2:
            let v = UIStoryboard.main.ThirdVC()
            present(v!, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

The main area of interest is **SidebarLauncher** class
what it does: when you call the **show()** method. it creates a UIView then it adds it to keywindow (i.e. your current View) and after that It adds the NavigationController.

To setup communication with the sidebar, I've created two Protocols

1. SidebarDelegate:

Sidebar delegate is the main protocol through which you get to know if the user has selected any ViewController or not.

2. NavigationDelegate: 
   this protocol is used for communication between the wrapper and the navigation controller. When user tap any button. it informs the wrapper class about it.

The wrapper class has a method **closeSidebar** which then closes the sidebar and inform the Controller class that sidebar is closed with option.

In sidebarDidClose, you can decide what to do with the selection made by user.

I was in a bit of hurry which is why I used **Int** whereas you should consider using struct or class whichever suits your need to identify which ViewController to open.

https://github.com/sahilmanchanda2/SidebarTest

Comment: Is there any way you can post your sample project on GitHub?

Comment: @NoahWilder I'm in office right now. Will upload After reaching home.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out as soon as you get the chance to upload it

Comment: @NoahWilder, I have added the project. let me know if you need anything

Comment: I just played around with it and customized some stuff and it works fantastically! Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I embed the side menu view controller in a navigation controller itself?

Comment: if you create UITableVIew or UICollectionVIew Programatically then there is no need of adding navigation controller. This can be done pretty quickly. just create UITableView or UICollectionView and add it to the view. set the datasource and delegate to SideMenuViewController and you are all good to go

Comment: @NoahWilder, let me know if you need help in this regard. Will be happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You need use an Coordinator

[raywenderlich Coordinator](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158-coordinator-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

[townsend Coordinator](https://will.townsend.io/2016/an-ios-coordinator-pattern)